# Why can't I access my Kubernetes service via its IP?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes service on GKE as follows:

```
$ kubectl describe service staging
Name:           staging
Namespace:      default
Labels:         <none>
Selector:       app=jupiter
Type:           NodePort
IP:             10.11.246.27
Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   31683/TCP
Endpoints:      10.8.0.33:1337
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

I can access the service from a VM directly via one of its endpoints (`10.8.0.21:1337`) or via the node port (`10.240.251.174:31683` in my case). However, if I try to access `10.11.246.27:80`, I get nothing. I've also tried ports 1337 and 31683.

Why can't I access the service via its IP? Do I need a firewall rule or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Service IPs are virtual IPs managed by kube-proxy. So, in order for that IP to be meaningful, the client must also be a part of the kube-proxy "overlay" network (have kube-proxy running, pointing at the same apiserver).

Pod IPs on GCE/GKE are managed by GCE [Routes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#routes), which is more like an "underlay" of all VMs in the network.

There are a couple of ways to access non-public services from outside the cluster. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664060/how-to-call-a-service-exposed-by-a-kubernetes-cluster-from-another-kubernetes-cl/31665248#31665248) they are in more detail, but in short:

1. Create a bastion GCE route for your cluster's services.
2. Install your cluster's kube-proxy anywhere you want to access the cluster's services.