# Communication between subnetwork and another subnetwork secondary IPv4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Here is my network problem on GCP :

- VPC : "main"

  - Subnetwork : "VPN" 10.0.2.0/24
  - Subnetwork : "kube" 10.52.0.0/16

    - Secondary IPv4 ranges for "kube" : "gke-services-range" 10.152.0.0/16

[image: Architecture Schema]

Could I communicate from my VM (`10.0.2.3`) in Subnetwork `VPN` to the secondary IPv4 of subnetwork `kube` : `gke-services-range` (`10.152.0.4`) ?

I tried but unfortunately (allow all ingress/egress in firewall) it doesn't seem to work natively... Even though it's part of the same VPC.

- VM --> GKE node : connection is OK, ping/ssh works
- GKE Node --> SVC : connection to SVC ok, curl is working
- VM --> SVC : not working, timeout with curl

Comment: How are you trying to communicate from VM(10.0.2.2) to gke-services(10.152.0.4)? Is it by pinging or establishing an SSH connection, etc? Is the IP 10.152.0.4 a pod or a service? If it is a service, what type of service is it? Please update the question with these details.

Comment: Can you run ```kubectl get pods -o wide``` and update the question with the results. I did the same replication and was able to ping from and to ```VM``` to ```node``` and ```pod``` IP and vice versa.

Comment: I just want to clarify if the NGINX SVC that you were trying to curl, is a pod IP or a service IP address (Type of Cluster IP: Nodeport or LoadBalancer)?

Comment: Hey James, thank you for your answers ! I can access to the pods IPs but I can’t access to the SVC (ClusterIP). I have no problem with nodeport/LB

Comment: But I think my problem is not a problem at all. ClusterIP should not be accessible from other network. However, I should have access to the SVC as my firewall is fully opened no ?

Comment: ClusterIP (default) - Exposes the Service on an internal IP in the cluster. This type makes the ```Service``` **only reachable from within the cluster**. That is why you cannot access your service via ClusterIP from outside the cluster (i.e. from your VM)

Comment: Again, if you are referring to ```SVC``` as the Cluster IP(default). You are not supposed to curl it. **It is a virtual IP, it is not routable**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***ClusterIP*** (default) exposes the `Service` on a [cluster-internal IP](https://blog.ovhcloud.com/getting-external-traffic-into-kubernetes-clusterip-nodeport-loadbalancer-and-ingress/#:%7E:text=in%20production%20environments.-,Using%20Kubernetes%20proxy%20and%C2%A0ClusterIP,-The%20default%20Kubernetes). This spec type makes the Service ***only reachable from within the cluster***. That is why you cannot access your service via ClusterIP from outside the cluster (i.e. your VM 10.0.2.3). Additionally, ***it is a virtual IP and not routed***. This is discussed in a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439181/how-can-i-access-the-kubernetes-service-through-clusterip#:%7E:text=From%20where%20are%20you%20trying%20to%20access%20clusterIP%3F%20The%20clusterIP%20(by%20default)%20only%20works%20from%20within%20the%20cluster.%20It%20is%20a%20virtual%20IP%2C%20not%20routed.).

**NodePort** exposes the service on the same port of each selected node in the cluster using NAT. It makes a Service accessible outside of the cluster by using `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`. But again, it uses the node ip and port and ***not the ClusterIP***