# Are there any best practices on how to connect a GKE Cluster with an on premise network?

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to connect a Google Kubernetes Cluster with an on-premise network over Cloud VPN.

The Problem are POD ip's and Virtual Service Ip's that I not able to reach.

Are there any best practices on how to do this in a secure and robust way?

Should I run an OpenVPN Pod in the cluster and connect to it?
Or run kube-proxy in my on-premise network?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your VPN to forward packets to your cluster as described in CJ's answer to [Google Container Engine and VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738500/google-container-engine-and-vpn).